# ORA-12154 when connecting to oracle in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-7-x64, oracleclient, ora-12154

i tried to run asp.net website locally on my P.C. in visual studio.
Website tries to connect to oracle database and fails with error :
ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

my P.C runs Windows 7 - 64-bit , and i have Oracle 10g - 32-bit client installed. 
i read on internet that i should install 64-bit oracle client instead.
I did so, and now i have both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle clients installed.
I set TNS_ADMIN environment variable , and i added new client's path to PATH variable, too.
tnsnames.ora exists and has an entry for database i am connecting to.

I still get the same error when i debug the website. How to tell my website to use the new Oracle client? do i have to reference different libraries? 
i use .NET framework 4 and sometimes 4.5, and i reference system.data.oracleclient library

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by un-installing 32-bit client and keeping only the 64-bit version.